# print variable in the alert

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

i have this model function for counting the number of users

```
public function get_employee_list($role_id) {
    $qStr = "SELECT
              count(admins.id)
             FROM
              admins
             WHERE
              admin_role=".$role_id;
              $query = $this->db->query($qStr);

    return    $query->row_array();

  }
```

and my controller function is like this

```
 public function delete_employee_role_ajax($role_id) {
        $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
        $response = $this->employee_model->get_employee_list($role_id);
        //print_r($response);
        if($response) {
            $objResponse->script( "bootbox.alert('$response +users are associated with this role and it cannot be deleted')" );
        }
        else {
        $response = $this->employee_model->delete_employee_role($role_id);
        $objResponse->script( "window.location.reload()" );
        }
        return $objRespons
```

}

i want to print the value of $response.

Comment: how you calling this controller action ?

Comment: function delete_employee_role(role_id) {
    bootbox.confirm("Delete this role?", function(result) {
        if(result == true) {
            xajax_delete_employee_role_ajax(role_id);
        }
    }); 
}

Comment: i am getting value in the $response, but unable to print in the alert

Answer (score 0):

You could try [encoding it as a JSON structure](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$encodedResponse = json_encode($response);
$objResponse->script("bootbox.alert('$encodedResponse +users are associated...')" );
```

Comment: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: encodedResponse</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/employees.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 94</p>

</div>{"xjxobj":[{"cmd":"js","data":"bootbox.alert(' +users are associated with this role and it cannot be deleted')"}]}

Comment: My bad, there is a typo on the first line: $encodedReponse should be $encodedResponse. Updated the answer with the correct variable name.